# recorrer array asociativo multidimensional en PHP con cualquier ciclo

Tags: php

//ME podrían ayudar con este arreglo que no quiere imprimir el 'periodo y carrera'

```
<?php
    $datos = array(
                        "periodo"   => 'Sep-Dic2018',
                        "carrera"   => 'ITIC',
                        "matricula" => array('18005xyz','18005abc','18005opq'),                    
                        "grupo"     => array('7A','7A','10A'),                           
                        "materia"   => array("PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES","PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES","TÓPICOS SELECTOS DE TI"),
                        "calif"     => array(10.00,9.00,8.50)
                        );

    $periodo = $datos['periodo'];
    $carrera = $datos['carrera'];
    $matricula = $datos['matricula'];
    $grupo = $datos['grupo'];
    $materia = $datos['materia'];
    $calificacion = $datos['calif'];


    foreach ($datos as $alumno => $valor) {
    echo "El almuno tiene $alumno: ".$valor[0]."</br>";
    echo "El almuno tiene $alumno: ".$valor[1]."</br>";
    echo "El almuno tiene $alumno: ".$valor[2]."</br>";
    }
    //y me tiene que salir a este similar en pantalla puede ser con cualquier ciclo, nadamas que yo lo hice con foreach pero no me sale....
    /*$alumno[0] = array( "matricula" =>'18005xyz', "grupo"=>'7A', "materia"=>"PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES", "calif"=>10.00, "periodo" =>'Sep-Dic2018', "carrera"=>'ITIC');
    $alumno[1] = array( "matricula" =>'18005abc', "grupo"=>'7A', "materia"=>"PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES", "calif"=>9.00, "periodo" =>'Sep-Dic2018', "carrera"=>'ITIC'); 
    $alumno[2] = array( "matricula" =>'18005opq', "grupo"=>'10A',"materia"=>"TÓPICOS SELECTOS DE TI",       "calif"=>8.50, "periodo" =>'Sep-Dic2018', "carrera" =>'ITIC');*/
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Periodo y carrera, dentro del `array asociativo`, son son strings. Distinto al resto de los elementos que son `arrays`.

```
array(
    "periodo"   => 'Sep-Dic2018',   
    "carrera"   => 'ITIC',
    ...
)
```

Cuando se hace un `foreach($array as $clave => $valor)`, para estos dos casos, `$clave` va a tomar los valores `"periodo"` y `"carrera"`, y `$valor` va a tomar los valores `string` `'Sep-Dic2018'` e `'ITIC'`.

Por este movtivo `$valor[0]` no tiene significado alguno para estos dos casos. Para imprimir los valores correspondientes hay que referirse a ellos como `$valor` directamente.

Para los otros elementos, que son `arrays`, sí necesitas los índices numéricos para referirte a los elementos individuales de esos `arrays` (`$valor[i]`).

```
array(
    ...
    "matricula" => array('18005xyz','18005abc','18005opq'),                    
    "grupo"     => array('7A','7A','10A'),                           
    "materia"   => array("PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES","PROGRAMACIÓN DE APLICACIONES","TÓPICOS SELECTOS DE TI"),
    "calif"     => array(10.00,9.00,8.50)
);
```

Para saber si un elemento es un array o no podes usar la función `is_array($valor)` que devuelve verdadero si el `$valor` es un array.

Con esta función podrias hacer cosas diferentes dependiendo del tipo de elemento con el que te encontras.

Por ejemplo podemos hacer algo así para imprimir todo los elementos de `$datos`:

```
function print_array($array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo $key . ': ' . '<br>';
            print_array($value);
        }else{
            echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
        }
    }
}

print_array($datos);
```